# PHP-5.4.44, Apache Phusion Passenger not supporting POST request parameters

Tags: php, json, apache

I have a php file that pulls JSON response from my database.

The problem is that the same file works fine on my local but not after I upload it to the server. There are parameters that I pass with the URL and the php code just goes to the else part towards the end as it cannot find the parameters

Any help on this would be appreciated.

the php code in my index file is below:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(1);

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'username') {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        if(isset($username) && !empty($username)) {
            $response = isUserRegistered($username);
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }

}
else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I have tried using `$_REQUEST['tag']` instead of `$_POST['tag']`

I tried `echo $_POST['tag']; die;` before the IF condition but that returns no data:

> response contains no data

Comment: Please post your code and any attempts to resolve the issue. Error messages are also helpful.

Comment: @rwking updated the question, please review and advise

Comment: The `if ($tag == 'username') {` and `if(isset($username) && !empty($username)){` don't have any corresponding else branch. If one of the conditions isn't true there will be no output. You might want to fix that and test again.

Comment: @VolkerK if that was the case, the system would not go to the else part    :     else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}

Comment: @VolkerK Tried what you suggested, still same result. It does not go to the inner-else condition

Comment: `There are parameters that I pass with the URL` - that would be a GET request then. POST parameters are in the request body, not "within" the URL. Exactly how do you pass the parameters?

Comment: My bad, i am passing it in the payload with the post request @VolkerK

Comment: Did you check with a client-side debugger/sniffer like e.g. firebug (esp. its network tab) that the browser/client sends the POST parameters as expected? [not for your localhost server; that apparently works; but for requests to your live server]

Comment: @VolkerK Yes, I did check, the post parameters are sent correctly to the live server

Comment: Instead of your `echo $_POST['tag']; die;` debug line please try `echo json_encode(array(
 'CONTENT_TYPE'=>$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'],
 'CONTENT_LENGTH'=>$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'],
 'QUERY_STRING'=>$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],
 'input' => file_get_contents('php://input'),
 'POST' => var_export($_POST, true)
)); die;` (sorry, no proper formatting in comments. Check the code before running ...as you always should ;-))

Comment: @VolkerK this is what it returns: {"CONTENT_TYPE":"application\/json","CONTENT_LENGTH":"26","QUERY_STRING":"","input":"tag=username&username=abc","POST":"array (\n)"}

Comment: _POST contains only the POST parameters that have been sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded name=value pairs. You're sending `application/json` (though the request body isn't valid JSON either).

Comment: I tried application/x-www-form-urlencoded and it returns     Response does not contain any data. May be something to do with the connection file. Wil; try to work on it and figure out. Thank you so much @VolkerK you've been great help

Comment: @VolkerK I was able to fix the issue. See answer I posted below. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the issue.
mysql_connect function was deprecated due to php version 5.4.
Also, the mysql option was not checked under phpversion section by default, makes me feel a little foolish that I didnt think about that before
Reverted the server php version to 5.3 and check mysql which took care of the issue

Comment: Hm, that can only mean that you had multiple issues. The answer doesn't seem to correspond to the original question, e.g. `and the php code just goes to the else part towards the end`: `require_once 'DB_Functions.php';` and `isUserRegistered` are not in that else-branch.